# Expressing subsets in the calculus of constructions

Tags: type-theory

The book I'm reading on the calculus of constructions suggests to treat subsets in the following way. Let's fix some type $S$ as representing the whole set of interest, and express a subset $V \subseteq S$ as some corresponding predicate $P : S \rightarrow *$. Then (set-theoretic) $x \in V$ is equivalent to (type-theoretic) $P x$ being inhabited, and all the usual notions of set union, intersection and so on are expressible as obvious combinations of the corresponding predicates. So far, so good.

When discussing this particular encoding, one of the alternatives considered is to associate each subset $V$ with some matching type $V_{ty}$. The mentioned drawbacks of the latter are the following:

1. Uniqueness of types (up to some equivalence) is broken — this one is obvious.
2. Typechecking becomes undecidable — and this one is raising questions for me.

So, typechecking becomes undecidable since predicates (in any reasonable set theory) can be pretty much arbitrary, and deciding whether a predicate holds (again, in set theory) might be equivalent to the halting problem. But, we know that CoC is strongly normalizing, so if we're limited to what we can do within the system, then all the predicates always halt, and we don't have this problem.

The questions I have then are:

1. By the very same argument, does that mean that the class of predicates expressible in CoC (and thus the class of subsets in CoC) is a strict subset of those in a reasonable set theory?
2. Can't we achieve the same effect on decidability by internalizing the predicates and limiting them to what we can do in CoC?
3. Am I missing anything else?

Comment: When you say "*some* matching type $V_{ty}$", do you mean some type that we can algorithmically build through some "matching" process or do you mean some type (in the existential way) that we decide to call it "a matching type"?

Comment: You say $S$ is a type in the CoC. Is $V\subseteq S$ or is $V$ a subset of the set of interest? Are you describing/comparing two ways to interpret set theory through the CoC?

Comment: 1. I didn't go that deep. I believe I only considered the "existential" approach, but trying to algorithmize building a type from a set description sounds interesting!
2. If I got your question right, $V$ is not necessarily a proper subset. The corresponding predicate would just be a "constantly true" proposition (something like $\lambda x:S. \bot \rightarrow \bot$ maybe).
3. Yes. Possibly even more than two — it's easy to imagine some ways having more subvariants.